# How to use ViewModel to update a TextView with the input of a EditText?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

I have 3 questions each displayed in a fragment. After each question there is a fragment that has a TextView which has the answer that was typed in in the EditText of the previous questions fragment. I followed the instructions of a tutorial but this somehow does not update the TextViews. How do I use the code shown here so the input of every question is only shown in the TextView of the next fragment? (fragments: question 1 --> answer 1 --> question 2 --> answer 2 --> question 3 --> answer 3)

Here is the code of the first two fragments and the ViewModel:

First Question Fragment:

```
public class FragmentQuestion1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnNavFrag1;
private EditText mEditTextQuestion1;
private SharedViewModel viewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_1, container, false);

    btnNavFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_question1);

    mEditTextQuestion1 = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_question_1);

    btnNavFrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            viewModel.getAnswer(1);

            ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String answer) {
            viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
            mEditTextQuestion1.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

First Answer overview Fragment:

```
public class FragmentAnswer1 extends Fragment {

private View btnNavFragAns1;
private TextView tv_answer1;
private SharedViewModel viewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_answer_1, container, false);

    btnNavFragAns1 = view.findViewById(R.id.next_question_1);

    tv_answer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_player_1_text_view);

    btnNavFragAns1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(3);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String answer) {
            viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
            tv_answer1.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

Shared View Model:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {


public HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>>(){{
    put(1, new MutableLiveData<String>());
    put(2, new MutableLiveData<String>());
    put(3, new MutableLiveData<String>());
}};



public MutableLiveData<String> getAnswer(int questionId) {
    return answers.get(questionId);
}

public void setAnswer(int questionId, String answer) {
    if (answers.get(questionId) != null) {
        answers.get(questionId).setValue(answer);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you are changing the answer inside the onChange callback, so this callback won't ever be called.

```
viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String answer) {
            viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
            tv_answer1.setText(answer);
        }
    });
```

What do I really recommend you is to use the 2-way data binding in this case.

Whether you don't want to, you can implement a TextWatcher on you edit text:

```
tv_answer1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher)
```

Implement like this:

```
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence answer, int i, int i1, int i2) {
             viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: When I implement this in my question fragment I get an error in this line: viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer); --> Wrong 2nd argument

Comment: I managed to change the code to this viewModel.setAnswer(1, (String) answer); so the error is gone but when I run the app it crashes after I typed in something into the EditText and I get this Log cat: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to java.lang.String --> this is the error I get after I changed the line viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);

Comment: You can cast SpannableStringBuilder to String indeed, have you tried to call the SpannableStringBuilder#toString() instead?

Comment: I don't know how to do this